# How exactly was this closed-form geometric summation derived?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, geometric-progressions

In my text book,it asks us to prove the statement below using induction. My question here isn't about answering that, but rather about how they got the sequence.

The problem shows:
For integers $$n \geq 3$$
$$\displaystyle 4^3+4^4+4^5+\cdot \cdot \cdot + 4^n = \frac{4(4^n -16)}{3}$$

Now we know that for a geometric progression, the formula for $$ar^k$$ looks somethings like:
$$\displaystyle \sum_{k =0}^{n} ar^k = \frac{ar^{n+1} -a}{r-1} , r \neq 1$$

Now how did did exactly did we arrive at this? If we plug 4 in as a and as r we get 
$$\displaystyle \frac{4(4^{n+1} -4)}{3}$$ 
Which is close, but has a -4 instead of a -16 in the numerator.

Comment: your $a=1$ and not $4$

Comment: Also notice that a given bounty cannot be recover. even if you do not give to somebody you cannot be refunded. Rather you can some reputation from Stark exchange by giving that to somebody. That 50 points were already discounted from your points. And you cannot be refunded. That was my first experience . Se here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631123/false-counterexample-for-for-all-sets-a-b-and-c-a-cap-b-c-a-cap/2487653#2487653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series $\sum_{k=0}^n ar^k$ is $a+ar+ar^2+\ldots+ar^n$ so the first term is $a$, and there are $n+1$ terms in total. Note that
$$4^3+4^4+\ldots+4^n = 4^3(1+4+4^2+\ldots+4^{n-3}).$$
Using the formula,
$$1+4+4^2+\ldots+4^{n-3}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}4^k=\frac{4^{n-2}-1}{4-1}=\frac{4^{n-2}-1}{3}$$
Therefore
$$4^3+4^4+\ldots+4^n =4^3\times\frac{4^{n-2}-1}{3}= \frac{4^{n+1}-4^3}{3}=\frac{4(4^n-16)}{3}$$

Comment: Okay, I think I follow up until you multiply the second equation by $4^3$. If we are excluding those first 3 terms from the summation, why are they involved. And in regard to the formula I gave earlier, would that make $a=4^3$?

Comment: I multiply by $4^3$ because the series you want is $4^3(1+4+\ldots+4^{n-3})$.  My expression in the second line is the bit inside the brackets. Multiplying this by $4^3$ gives the original series. You could instead take $a=4^3$ and $r=4$, and then you will also need to sum from $k=0$ to $n-3$.