# Integration identity proof

Tags: integration, derivatives, polynomials

I'm trying to prove the following identity:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(x)\cdot\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P'(x)\cdot\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx$

What I've done:
I tried using integration by parts and got here:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(x)\cdot\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=P(x)\cdot\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}e^{-x^{2}}\,|^\infty_{-\infty} -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P'(x)\cdot\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx$

How can I explain that the left expression equals 0. P($\infty$) can be $\infty$ and then $\infty \cdot 0$ is not defined and I can't say it equals 0.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: $P(x)$ must increase awfully fast if it goes to $\infty$ faster than the exponential goes to zero.  Are you given any limits on what $P(x)$ might be?

Comment: No. All I know is that it is some polynomial.

Comment: OK, then, I think Guy Fsone has you covered in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
Since setting $X=\frac{x^2}{2m} \to \infty~~~ as~~~x\to \pm \infty  $ for $m\in \Bbb N$ then, $$x^m e^{-x^2} =\left[ x^2 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2m}}\right]^m =\left[ 2m X e^{-X}\right]^m  $$

$$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}x^m e^{-x^2} = \lim_{X\to \infty} =\left[ 2m X e^{-X}\right]^m =0 .~~~\forall m\in\Bbb N$$

Therefoere $$ \color{red}{\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}P(x)e^{-x^2} = 0}$$

Comment: Is that ok now see the edit

Comment: It is classical that $\lim_{x\to \infty}xe^{-x} = 0$ by defintion of $e^x$

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Comment: If later you want ot recover this result . Click on the up arrow and the green check . E.g see here, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631123/false-counterexample-for-forall-a-b-and-c-we-have-a-cap-b-c/2487653#2487653.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{-x^2}$ is a [Schwartz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space), hence $\lim_{|x|\to +\infty}P(x)\frac{d^m}{dx^m}e^{-x^2}=0$ holds for any $m\geq 0$ and any polynomial $P(x)$.